# Get the overflow items in next line

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical menu having an item "Click here to get the scientific name".
[image]

on `hover` it is showing like

[image]

I need to get the overflow part after the black background image to be in the next line(i cannot increase the image width at all.). How can I write the style for that.

**css:**

on `hover`

```
{    
display: block;
background: url('/../.png') no-repeat 0px 2px #2F2F31;
text-decoration: none;
color:..;
}
```

This is coming under

```
<td> 
<div id="first">
    <ul id="second">
       <li><a href="">Click here to get the scientific name</a>
```

And css:

```
#first {
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    min-height: 50px;
    float: left;
}


ul#second {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 50px 0px 12px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid 
    #C8C8C8;
}


ul#second li {
    border-top: 1px solid 
    #C8C8C8;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
}


ul#second li a {
    color: 
    #004C8E;
    margin: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 12px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: url('/../.png') no-repeat 0px 2px;
}                  


td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: 
  transparent;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with your HTML and css section for the above example?

Comment: add some code to your question..and make it a little bit clear

Comment: Can you edit the height of the element?

Comment: @Charlie: I cannot increase the height.

Comment: If you want the text that's too long to go to the next line, but you can't increase the height of the element, then the rest of the text is going to be half on the background and half off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On hover, you should explicitly set the `width` of the element to equal the width of the image.

Answer (score 1):

FOr this you can use `word-wrap:break-word;`. Write like this:

```
p{
 word-wrap:break-word;
}
```